# Spring rejected value for time

Tags: java, mysql, sql, spring, time

Well, I have an html form with "input type= time" to save into a sql.time type but spring rejected to save it into the object. I've already tried to set "input type= time step= 1" because I was thinking that the problem was up to the seconds field. But still spring rejected my value.

What should I do to take time from an html form and save it into a sql.time data type? I was searching but nothing showed up to me.

EDIT: code above:

```
@GetMapping("/nuovo-ascolto")
    public String viewNuovoAscolto(Model model){
        model.addAttribute("nuovoAscolto", new Registro_Programmi_Guardati());
        return "nuovo-ascolto";
    }
```

Model:

```
public class Registro_Programmi_Guardati {
    //others attributes
    private Time orario;
    //other methods
    public Time getOrario() {
        return orario;
    }

    public void setOrario(Time orario) {
        this.orario = orario;
    }

}
```

Thymeleaf (with no errors)

```
<p>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;ORA: <input type="time" step= "1" style="position: absolute; right: 5%;" th:field="*{orario}"/></p>
```

Error on console:

```
Field error in object 'registro_Programmi_Guardati' on field 'orario': rejected value [21:00] //21:00 is the time i've inserted into the html form
```

Comment: Are you reading the HTML file directly from Java ?

Comment: yep, I'm using spring mvc. I have the html file into the templates directory and a class to fill with the input received from the html form by using a Model.

Comment: @Pikappa : Please share your relevant  line of codes, table schema if any and actual error which is coming for better understanding of problem

Comment: I've just edited the post with the relevant line of codes and the error on console output.

Comment: Using `java.sql.Time` won't magically convert your `String` parameter. You need to parse the posted parameter value.

Comment: For java.sql.Date works fine without any parsing. Anyway, what should I do please?

Comment: For starters don't use `java.sql` as field types in your code... You have now tied your whole codebase to JDBC. If you are on java 8 use one of the available types like `LocalTime` else use the excellent Joda Time library. (Not to mention the atrocity that the `java.sql.Time` and friends are). Spring will now properly do conversion when using the ISO format to submit the values.

Comment: Registro_Programmi_Guardati what is it?c#?c?cpp? definetly not Java class